# VB Script to count the number of rows

Tags: csv, vbscript

I have written a VB script to count the number of rows from several CSV files and save in a File in FileRecordCount.csv file with the filename and number of rows. The code does not show any errors at all.
But the script is not working at all. I don't know what is the problem. Any help Any help would be greatly appreciated!????

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

vbsFile = Wscript.ScriptName
vbsFilePath = Wscript.ScriptFullName
sFolder = left(vbsFilePath,len(vbsFilePath)-(len(vbsFile)+1))
ResultsFile = sFolder & "\FileRecordCount.csv"

For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder(sFolder).Files
    If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)) = "CSV" Then

        oFile =  objFile.path
        Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(oFile, ForReading)
        RowCount = 0

        Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
            WScript.Echo objFile.ReadLine
            RowCount = RowCount + 1
        Loop

        'need to make a new file to write the results to
        FileName = objFSO.GetFileName(ResultsFile)
        strText = FileName & "," & RowCount

        Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(ResultsFile, ForWriting)
        objFile.WriteLine strText

       objFile.Close

    End if

Next

MsgBox "FileRowCount Complete"
```

Comment: Try changing your FileRecordCount.csv output file name to use a different extension, such as FileRecordCount.txt, as it appears to be getting caught up in your CSV input processing.

Comment: Hi, It is not working. what the code do now, It just open the file and read the contents of each file.

Comment: You are using the looping variable `objFile` to point to the result file within the loop, use another variable for opening the result file. It is better to open the file before the loop and close after the loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert txt file to excel in vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685536/convert-txt-file-to-excel-in-vbscript)

Answer (score 3):

The script has multiple issues. First, as @Flakes stated, the same objFile variable is used for the files being processed and the results file. Second, the results filename is being written to the results file instead of each processed file name. Additionally, the variable "oFile" is a string, so would be better named "strFile" and the script path directory can be derived a bit more elegantly. Also, as per @Flakes, I moved the results file open before the loop and the results file close after the loop and I named the results file with a .txt extension so it doesn't get processed as one of the CSV files. Also added a Create = True flag to the results file open, so it doesn't have to pre-exist.

Here is the edited script:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const Create = True

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sFolder = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
ResultsFile = sFolder & "\FileRecordCount.txt"
Set objResultsFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(ResultsFile, ForWriting, Create)

For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder(sFolder).Files
  If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)) = "CSV" Then
    strFile =  objFile.path
    Set objReadFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, ForReading)
    RowCount = 0
    FirstLine = True
    Do Until objReadFile.AtEndOfStream
      Line = objReadFile.ReadLine
      RowCount = RowCount + 1
      If FirstLine Then ColumnCount = UBound(Split(Line,",")) + 1
      FirstLine = False
    Loop
    objReadFile.Close
    strText = strFile & "," & RowCount & "," & ColumnCount
    objResultsFile.WriteLine strText
  End if
Next
objResultsFile.Close
WScript.Echo "File row/column count complete"
```

Comment: This. Except I wouldn't re-use the For Each variable `objFile` so change `Set objFile = objFSO...` to a different name like `Set readFile = objFSO...etc` or something.

Comment: @BdR Good point. Change made.

Comment: Added code to count the number of columns, based on the first line in the file.