# VB Script to count the number of columns

Tags: csv, vbscript, filesystemobject

I have written a VB script to count the number of columns from several CSV files and save in a File in FileColumnCount.csv file with the filename and number of columns. But the script is not working at all. My logic for counting number of columns is wrong. I am trying to work my logic with Instr to find the occurrence of comma. But I fail. Any help would be greatly appreciated!????

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const Create = True

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sFolder = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
ResultsFile = sFolder & "\FileColumnCount.txt"
Set objResultsFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(ResultsFile, ForWriting, Create)

For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder(sFolder).Files
  If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)) = "CSV" Then
    strFile =  objFile.path
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, ForReading)
    ColumnCount = 0
    line_no = 0
    Do Until textstream.AtEndOfStream
      line_no = line_no
      line = textstream.ReadLine
      MsgBox line_no & " : " & line, 0, "Reading..."
    If instr(",",line_no) > 0 then
      instr(",",line_no)
      Count = Count +1
      Mid(line_no,instr(",",line_no)+1,1)
    Loop  
    objFile.Close
    strText = strFile & "," & ColumnCount
    objResultsFile.WriteLine strText
  End if
Next
objResultsFile.Close
MsgBox "FileColumnCount Complete"
```

Comment: Also related question - [VB Script to count the number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70105327)

Comment: You might want to look into the `Split` function.

Comment: You've managed (again) to make many errors in a small script. For example, "line_no = line_no" does nothing. Did you mean to increment line_no?  Also, you've used "line_no" in your Instr instead of "line". Start with the working script answer from your last question and make one *small* change at a time and CHECK the value of your variables using **Wscript.echo**. Run your script using **Cscript** to quickly see the results in the console.

Comment: Think through your logic. Do your CSV files really have different numbers of columns in each row or does each file have a consistent number of columns?  If so, you only need to count columns of the first row. Based on your non-working code, it appears that you're trying to count the total number of fields in the file. For a normal CSV file, you would get the column count (number of commas) from the first line only and then multiply that by the total number of rows at the end of the script.

Comment: @sdf I added code to the row count script to also count the number of columns (based on the first line in the file). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70104712/vb-script-to-count-the-number-of-rows