# Format the data from Textfile to a CSV file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, active-directory

I'm writing a script in VB Script to format Active directory data. I am using a Bat Script to produce the output in txt and I want to make a VB Script to format the data with headers.

My Batch script is

```
dsquery * -limit 0 -filter (objectclass=computer) -attr Name distinguishedName operatingSystem operatingSystemVersion whenChanged whenCreated > fullq.txt
```

The VB Script that I have is this currently

```
Option Explicit

Dim FSO, TextPath, CSVPath
Dim Textline, oText, oCSV
Dim CN, OU, i

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

TextPath = "fullq.txt"
Set oText = FSO.OpenTextFile(TextPath,1)

CSVPath = "fullq.csv"
Set oCSV = FSO.CreateTextFile(CSVPath, 2 ,False)

oCSV.WriteLine("Name,DistinguishedName,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemVersion,whenChanged,whenCreated")
oCSV.WriteLine

oText.SkipLine
Do Until oText.AtEndOfStream
    Textline = oText.ReadLine()

    OU = Split(TextLine, ",")
    CN = Mid(OU(0), 5)

    oCSV.Write CN & ","
    For i = 1 To UBound(OU)
        oCSV.Write OU(i)
        If i < UBound(OU) Then
            oCSV.Write("/")
        End If
    Next
    oCSV.Writeline
Loop

oCSV.WriteLine
oCSV.Close
```

The problem i have is the operatingSystem, operatingSystemVersion, whenCreated and whenChanged data is in distinguishedName column. I want it to be in their own respective column. The code above is mainly for *DistinguishedName*. I added new attribute which are *operatingSystem, operatingSystemVersion, whenChanged, whenCreated*. For distinguishedName, i would like to replaces the comma with "/" whereas the rest of the attributes I would like it to be written in their own respective column. I cant use PowerShell as the company blocked it.

The Output in the CSV look like this:

```
Name,DistinguishedName,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemVersion,whenChanged,WhenCreated

PC1,OU=1/OU=2/OU=3/DC=4/DC=COM    Window    123    12/12/12 10:10:10 12/12/12 10:10:10 , , ,
```

- Note that the comma represent new column

As written above, i tried this VB Script but the operatingSystem, operatingSystemVersion, whenCreated and whenChanged data is in distinguishedName column. I want it to be in their own respective column.

This is how the the fullq.txt would look like:

```
Name        DistinguishedName              OperatingSystem        OperatingSystemVersion   whenChanged        WhenCreated
PC1         OU=1/OU=2/OU=3/DC=4/DC=COM     Window                    123 
      12/12/12 10:10:10     12/12/12 10:10:10
```

Comment: This is odd. PowerShell is designed for this type of work. Why is PowerShell blocked and VBScript allowed? That's the opposite of what one would expect. Is it really blocked or do you just have to set the execution policy?

Comment: The company block PowerShell from running as it is consider privilege user. hences I can't use PowerShell

Comment: Please post at least one sample line from the file `fullq.txt` (I don't have an AD environment set up to get the output myself).

Comment: Hi, I have tried to put the output of fullq.txt to the best of my ability in the post but its basically the headers and values, the headers and values are separated using space

Comment: What you posted for `fullq.txt` does not make sense. Your script splits on commas, yet there are no commas in that sample input file. Please recheck. I also can't see how you are getting three trailing commas in your output.

Comment: The script was mainly for distinguishedName as it had multiply comma, now I want to add more attribute. I research about it online but to no avail as most of it have scripted it using PowerShell

Comment: No need for explanations. Please edit your question so that I can reproduce your output. Either the input must contain commas or the script must not split on commas.

Comment: You must edit the sample `fullq.txt` or edit the script. As it stands, I cannot reproduce your output, using the posted script and the posted input. And don't just edit. Test what you post!

Comment: For now, I'm assuming your input sample is correct and the code that splits on commas can be removed. See answer below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert txt file to excel in vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31685536)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the `fullq.txt` sample provided, the input can be split on `"  "` (two spaces) and then ignore empty entries and trim results:

```
Const Excel = True

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

TextPath = "fullq.txt"
Set oText = oFSO.OpenTextFile(TextPath,1)

CSVPath = "fullq.csv"
Set oCSV = oFSO.CreateTextFile(CSVPath,2,True)

If Excel Then oCSV.WriteLine "SEP=,"
oCSV.WriteLine "Name,DistinguishedName,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemVersion,whenChanged,whenCreated"

oText.SkipLine

Do Until oText.AtEndOfStream
    NewLine = ""
    Textline = oText.ReadLine
    aTextLine = Split(Textline,"  ")
    For i = 0 To UBound(aTextLine)
      If aTextLine(i)<>"" Then
        If NewLine<>"" Then NewLine = NewLine & ","
        NewLine = NewLine & Trim(aTextLine(i))
      End If
    Next
    oCSV.Writeline NewLine
Loop

oText.Close
oCSV.Close
```

Note that the sample input contained no commas, so I removed the code that splits on commas.

Comment: Hi sorry, recently was busy with something, i tried your code, but it doesnt work as it keep going so its i need to end the task for it to stop running. I recently tried breaking up the codes in to many parts and found the problem. I will try to solve it first, if i cant, i will modify the question. Thanks for genuinely helping me! so sorry for suddenly deleting

Comment: Based on the input sample, it looks like the only issue with the script I originally posted is that I forgot to reset Newline on each iteration. That line has now been added. Please retest. If the output is still not correct, please post a larger input sample.

Comment: Got it, will test it in two days time, thank you very much

Comment: Hi, i have test your answer and i like how it is but would like to ask is it possible to write data in their own column? if yes, how? because as of now, the output, all the data is in column A like this "name,distinguishedName,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemVersion,whenChanged,whenCreated". Would it be possible for each data to be in their own column?

Comment: Are you talking about importing that CSV file into a spreadsheet, such as Excel? If so, that's just a matter of how you load the file. If you have Excel installed and double click the CSV, it will load into a single column, but if you use File Open, you will get options to tell it to split on commas and then it will load in separate columns.

Comment: If you are using Excel, then it will automatically split on commas if the first line of the CSV  file is `SEP=,`. I've modified the script to make that an option.